# Lengthy delays when using ActiveMQ Ajax Client

Tags: java, ajax, jms, tomcat7, activemq-classic

I am testing the basic ActiveMQ AjaxServlet service to communicate with a back end ActiveMQ service. The issue I am having is that the time it takes to receive the message from the queue using the ajax client is sometimes 20+ seconds. The length of the delay is completely different every time but it is long enough that I am concerned about going forward with the solution. I have tried the prototype adapter and the jquery adapter and both exhibit the same issues. I have tried multiple browsers and the same issues persists. I have excellent connectivity with the remote queue and there is no delay there.

**Edit**

I see that the message is being delayed 25 seconds which is the timeout of the ajax connection. I don't think this is the correct behavior and it should break when the message is received,then reconnect. Is this the correct assumption?

ActiveMQ Version : 5.9.0 
Firefox: 28 
Chrome: Newest Release 
Tomcat: 7.0.52

**web.xml**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.activemq.brokerURL</param-name>
    <param-value>tcp://remoteaddress.example:61616</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>AjaxServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.activemq.web.AjaxServlet</servlet-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MessageServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.activemq.web.MessageServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MessageServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/q/message/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AjaxServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/q/ajax/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/amq/prototype.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/amq/amq_prototype_adapter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/amq/amq.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

  var amq = org.activemq.Amq;
  amq.init({ 
    uri: 'q/ajax',
    logging: true
  });

  var myHandler =
  {
    rcvMessage: function(message)
    {
       alert("received "+message);
    }
  };

  var myDestination='queue://com.broadworks.dms.client';

  var myMessage = '<message>foooooo barrrr</message>';
  var myId = '1231234';

  amq.addListener(myId, myDestination, myHandler.rcvMessage);


  try {
  amq.sendMessage(myDestination, myMessage);
  } catch (err) {
    alert(err);
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to use ActiveMQ's JavaScript library for building web apps that connected to ActiveMQ.  I switched to using their websockets interface though and never went back.  Just turn on the websocket interface as described here: http://activemq.apache.org/mqtt.html.  Then use the STOMP over WebSocket library from here: http://jmesnil.net/stomp-websocket/doc/

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I ended up going the same route. I fixed the gwt activemq library to work with websockets and it worked perfectly.

Comment: What if the network doesn't support websocket however it does allow the AJAX connection?  any advice on how to speed things up?

Answer (score 0):

It's a regression bug! I provided a patch at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-5182.
Compiled version at https://bitbucket.org/greyfairer/apache-activemq/downloads